# how to change spaces like dvd player?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to program an application that changes spaces the way DVD Player does on OS X (screenshot of the transition below, but it may not be helpful because I cannot get my timing right). How can I make my application open a window, and move into a different space the way DVD Player does?

[image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a new feature in OS X Lion. It's called Fullscreen apps.  You'll want to look at the documentation for how to get your app ready for Fullscreen:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html